# I can't run my controller with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(int id, int quantity)
    {
        ShoppingCart sc = new ShoppingCart();
        sc.id = id;
        sc.Quantity = quantity;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        { 
           db.ShoppingCart.Add(sc);
           db.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Products");
         }
       return View("Index");
    }
```

This is my view:

```
$(".add-to-cart").click(function () { 

        var dataObject = JSON.parseInt({
            'id': item.id,
            'quantity': item.quantity
        });

            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",  
                url: "ShoppingCarts/AddToCart",   
                contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
                data: dataObject,
                dataType: "html",
                success: successFunc,
                error: errorFunc
            });

            function successFunc(data, status) {
                alert('success');
            }

            function errorFunc() {
                alert('error');
            }
    });
```

In ajax there are success and error functions but neither of them even work. What am i doing wrong? I couldn't figure it out can you help me please. thanks

Comment: You've shown us the Javascript, how about the actual HTML? Does the button you are clicking have the `add-to-cart` CSS class on it for example? Do you have an errors in the console? Have you actually loaded jQuery? Where in the flow is the above Javascript?

Comment: yes it have class. I don't have any errors but the jquery method is working fine.

Comment: Can you actually show it then? We need to see more context.

Comment: <button class="add-to-cart" data-id="@item.Id"> Add To Cart</button>

Comment: this is my button and the method is working when the button clicked there is no problem about that

Comment: 1. Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: 2. What is `item`?

Comment: no i dont have any errors and item is my model object

Comment: What model object? Where does it come from? Can you please supply an [mcve] as this is impossible to figure out without more detail.

Comment: it comes from database other informations are useless i have a problem with the ajax part.

Comment: I'll say again, we need a [mcve]. Until then, this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have full context here but this is what you will have to do anyway to make it work, it is tested (not only my guess from head):

1.) Change your datatype to 'json' and contentType to 'application/json'

2.) What is with `JSON.parseInt`? Change it to `JSON.stringify`

3.) Instead of id and quantity make complex model (class) with those properties:

```
public class MyData{
   int quantity;
   int id;
}
```

and change your controller like this:

```
   public ActionResult AddToCart(MyData myData)
```

It will work but you can also can try `[HttpPost]` attribute on simple properties like this:
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] string name) { ... }

Note however that this won't do it in your case because it is only allowed to have one `[HttpPost]` attribute on `action`.

4.) `item` variable seems undefined here. Define it :)

```
  var item={
  quantity:5,
  id:4
 }
```

Comment: what do i need to do that i don't understand?

Comment: @Vlado This is not relevant at all, OP isn't even reaching the server (which you can tell because `success` and `error` fucntions don't run.

Comment: Maybe, but it never get those values on server if it does not make required changes.

Comment: Either `success` or `error` will be called regardless whether the server is hit or not.

Comment: I updated answer with suggestion to change datatype of ajax to 'application/json'.

Comment: I've never heard about a datatype *"javascript/json"*

Comment: Yes, but the `dataType` should be `json` only. But it *still* doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: *"application/json"* is a content type

Comment: Unfortunately you are still just *guessing* at the answer here. And your guess is wrong.

Comment: But it doesn't for the OP and that's the issue here. We have zero idea of the context which is the problem.

Comment: Also in the Ajax call we cannot guaranty the url is correct. It doesn't start from server root so it depends on current location. I would suggest to use a Razor helper. Otherwise just wait for OP to try this and give feedback.

Comment: I would be more than happy if I would receive this kind of answer. It would likely be of great help to him. I just created simple application. This is working. We don't know full context, but would be very very helpfull I think especially when I tested it. Just make sure to have variable 'item' defined

Comment: So the list of things (off the top of my head) that could be wrong: incorrect MVC routing, spelling error in the URL, no idea what the mystery object `item` is, the nonexistant `JSON.parseInt` function, etc. The problem isn't that you tried to help (which is appreciated) it's that we have no idea what the problem is so this is just a guess.